# Norm of $(1+\sqrt{2})^n$?

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory

How do we find the norm of $(1+\sqrt{2})^n$ $ \forall n\geq1$? 
The norm of $a+b\sqrt{D}$ is defined as $a^2-b^2D$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $D$ is a square free integer.
**P.S**- This question comes from Ring theory when we try to find the units of the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$
Any hint is welcome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT:** Norm is multiplicative

Prove that, then it's easy

Comment: You'r welcome. There are a lot of way to prove that it is multiplicative, either by direct computation (which is the way I suggest to you if norm was defined to be just that subtraction as you wrote) , or in a more conceptual way (which should be the preferred way to do stuff in general, but you must digest some more theory in order to understand it :) )

Comment: Please can you tell me how to prove that the norm is multiplicative in a conceptual way?

Comment: if you are working in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ you check that it's a separable extension over $\mathbb{Q}$, namely, that it has degree=number of possible embedding in $\mathbb{C}$. The embeddings (which has to be the identity on $\mathbb{Q}$ are easily found to be uniquely determined by where they send $\sqrt{2}$, namely you have 2 choices $\sigma_{1,2}\colon \sqrt{2}\mapsto \pm \sqrt{2}$ (why? only these two, you can think over it al little) and you can define the norm of an element $\alpha$ as $\sigma_1(\alpha)\sigma_2(\alpha)$, which is clearly multiplicative because embeddings are

Comment: it's a  very standard argument, you can find in any book about algebraic number theory, so I didn't put lots of details in my comment above

Answer (score 2):

Note that the norm is multiplicative. I.e. $N(x)N(y)=N(xy)$.

Thus as an easy consequence, we can see that $N(x^n)=N(x)^n$

So we just need to find the norm of $1+\sqrt{2}$, which by definition is $1-2\cdot 1^2=-1$